Spaces between methods
I'm using BiomeJS on a TypeScript project.
If there are two methods separated by more than one vertical line, biome will delete the extra lines putting only one line between them.
If however there are no empty lines between two methods, it just leaves them.
Is there any way to force it to have one and only one vertical space between all methods/functions, etc.?

Unfortunately, that's not possible, and there isn't an option for this particular use case.
Biome follows Prettier formatting style.
